# duplicate entries error from the database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have something like the following domain-structure (it's a legacy database!):

```
class Contract implements Serializable {
    int type
    ...
    hasMany = [attachments: Attachment]

    static mapping = {
        attachments cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}

class Attachment implements Serializable {
    static belongsTo = [contract: Contract]
    int attNo
    String name

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned', composite: ['contract', 'attNo']
    }
}
```

The contract has - depending on it's type - a few default attachments which should be deleted and recreated if the type changes.

For this I created a service which is called just before saving the edited contract. (The service doesn't have the @Transactional annotation, to have it running in the same transaction than the save/update of the contract.)

```
class AttachmentService {

    def removeAttRecords(int contractId) {
        Contract contract = Contract.get(contractId)
        def records = contract.getAttachments()
        for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
            Attachment record = records[i]
            contract.removeFromAttachments(record)
        }
    }

    def insertAttRecord(int contractId, String name) {
        def contract = Contract.get(contractId)
        def records = contract.attachments
        int maxNo = 0
        for (attachment record: records) {
            if (record.attNo > maxNo) 
                maxNo = record.attNo
        }

        Attachment att = new Attachment()
        att.contract = contract
        att.attNo = maxNo +1
        att.name = name
        att.validate()
        att.save(insert: true, flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }

    def createDefaultRecords(int newType, int contractId) {
        if (newType == 1) {
            removeAttRecords(contractId)
        } else if (newType == 2) {
            removeAttRecords(contractId)
            insertAttRecord(contractId, "Attachment XYZ")
            insertAttRecord(contractId, "Attachment ABC")
        } else if (newType == 3) {
            removeAttRecords(contractId)
            insertAttRecord(contractId, "Attachment DEF")
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is now, that I get a **duplicate entries** error from the database in the **insertAttRecord->att.save call**, if I call the **createDefaultRecords** method in my service. Because of the deletion and the recreation.

I currently have no idea, how I could work around it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `id generator: 'assigned'` for the Attachment class. That means you have to set its id (the primary key) yourself. It looks like since you're not assigning it the new entries will all have the same id, hence the duplicate entries failure.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, in the above (shortened) example I had a typo. (corrected now). The the assigned key is a composite which contains the contract and the attNo (attachment number). Double-checked that in my code and it contains the assignement also. I think it must have something to do with the deletion in the beginning, that the deletion is not executed correctly...

Comment: Have you tested the method removeAttRecords independently? Also you could remove all attachments with this command:

`Contract.get(contractId).attachments.clear()`

Is it possible that the attachment isn't an orphan? Some other reference to it...?

Comment: Please be aware that the method insertAttRecord isn't thread safe. If called by separated threads at the same time for the same contract you might end up with colliding ids.

Comment: Thanks @douglas, I changed the deletion to "for (int i = records.size(); i > 0; i--) {  Attachment record = records[i -1]" ... silly mistake... but nevertheless, changing from a contract type with attachments to a contract type without ones and vice versa is perfectly working. But not the change from a contract-type with attachments to another contract-type with other attachments (where the new attachments will get the same keys as the deleted ones... Even a session-flush (Contract.withSession { session -> session.flush() }) makes no difference.

Comment: Well... A few more things you could try:

* Calling record.delete() to make sure they are gone once removed from the contract;
* Passing the contract reference to each method instead of calling Contract.get(contractId) each time (maybe I'm being paranoid but I don't trust the 1st level cache so much);
* Give it a try without reusing IDs so you know that's really the problem, but maybe there is a bug related to composited IDs... it would be nice to find out and report;

Comment: BTW, have you tried contract.getAttachments().clear() instead of iterating each element? contract.getAttachments() returns a Set, not an ArrayList. It doesn't seem like a good idea to access each element using the array notation (records[i]).

Comment: with an additional `record.delete()` or with only a `record.delete()` I had no luck (as described here [link]http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/ - I haven't used the `clear()` method, because in my original code only records with a special content should be deleted. Your remark regarding passing the contract-reference is something I'll implement, looks alot better than getting everytime the contract from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around my problem with the following code:

```
class AttachmentService {

    def removeAttRecords(int contractId) {
        Attachment.executeUpdate("delete from Attachment att where att.contract.id = ?", [contractId])
    }

    def insertAttRecord(int contractId, int nextMaxNo, String name) {
        Attachment att = new Attachment()
        att.contract = Contract.get(contractId)
        att.attNo = nextMaxNo
        att.name = name
        att.validate()
        att.save(insert: true, flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }

    def createDefaultRecords(int newType, int contractId) {
        def result = Attachment.executeQuery("select max(att.attNo) from Attachment att where att.contract.id = ?", contractId)
        if (result[0] == null) result[0] = 0;
        int currMaxNo = result[0]

        if (newType == 1) {
            removeAttRecords(contractId)
        } else if (newType == 2) {
            removeAttRecords(contractId)
            insertAttRecord(contractId, currMaxNo +1, "Attachment XYZ")
            insertAttRecord(contractId, currMaxNo +2, "Attachment ABC")
        } else if (newType == 3) {
            removeAttRecords(contractId)
            insertAttRecord(contractId, currMaxNo +1, "Attachment DEF")
        }
    }
}
```

After discussing with the db-designer, it would be ok to handle that in this way.
(but I'd still like to know, why it wasn't working, even with a session-flush... :-)